# str.split() includes empty elements in returned List

Tags: python, string, split

I'm trying to use the split() function to split a path's name into tokens separated by '/'.

Example:

```py
path = "/a/b///c/../d/.//f"
list = path.split('/')
```

I expected the output list to be `['a', 'b', 'c', '..', 'd', '.', 'f']` but the actual output is `['', 'a', 'b', '', '', 'c', '..', 'd', '.', '', 'f']`.

Why are there empty elements in the returned list? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you do `"a/b".split('/')`, you'd expect 'a' and 'b'.  When you do `"/b".split('/')`, you have the same number of slashes, so you should get the same number of results.  Otherwise, you couldn't tell the difference between that and `"b".split('/')`.

Comment: Note that the official documentation for the `split` function literally tells you that this will happen, over on https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split: `consecutive delimiters are not grouped together and are deemed to delimit empty strings (for example, '1,,2'.split(',') returns ['1', '', '2'])`.

Comment: `str.split` doesn't know about any special conventions related to valid path names and repeated path delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try something like:

```
path = '/a/b///c/../d/.//f'
list = path.split('/')
newList = [p for p in list if p != '']
```

The output should be `['a', 'b', 'c', '..', 'd', '.', 'f']`

Answer (score 2):

To parse path string as you have in your question, I'd recommend using [`PurePath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pure-paths):

```py
from pathlib import PurePath

path = "/a/b///c/../d/.//f"

print(PurePath(path).parts)
```

Prints:

```
('/', 'a', 'b', 'c', '..', 'd', 'f')
```

You can check/strip the leading `/` if you want afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Split using Regex would be the cleanest approach...

```py
import re

re.split(r'\/+', path)
```

The Regex matches one or more forward slashes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use third-party or even standard libraries... Yes, regular expressions are a good way, but I think these two are better:

1. Using `filter`:

```py
path = '/a/b///c/../d/.//f'
list_ = list(filter(lambda x: x, path.split('/')))
print(list_)  # ['a', 'b', 'c', '..', 'd', '.', 'f']
```

2. Using list comprehension:

```py
path = '/a/b///c/../d/.//f'
list_ = [i for i in path.split('/') if i]
print(list_)  # ['a', 'b', 'c', '..', 'd', '.', 'f']
```

However, I like the first one more because it's easier to work with different functions!

Answer (score -1):

To achieve the expected output, you can use the os.path.normpath() function to normalize the path and then split it:

```
import os

path = "/a/b///c/../d/.//f"
normalized_path = os.path.normpath(path)
path_list = normalized_path.split(os.path.sep)

print(path_list)
```

This should give you the desired output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', '..', 'd', '.', 'f']
```

The os.path.normpath() function simplifies the path by removing redundant elements like '//' and '/../', and then you can split it using the platform-specific path separator (os.path.sep).